# Update/Edit Database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I know This is something simple yet I cannot do it right or find any answer searching google.

I want to update/edit the data. in the database server, by clicking the data that display on my `DataGridView`.

below is my sub Edit, the code is not automatically fetching the record to the textbox.

```
Private Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click

  Dim transaction As SqlTransaction = Nothing

  With New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Try
      Call .Open()
      transaction = .BeginTransaction()
      With .CreateCommand()
        .Transaction = transaction
        .CommandText = "UPDATE [tbl_info] SET [Name]=@Name WHERE [ID]=@ID;"
        With .Parameters
          .AddWithValue("ID", txtID.Text)
          .AddWithValue("Name", txtName.Text)
        End With
        Call .ExecuteNonQuery()
        Call transaction.Commit()
        Call MessageBox.Show("has been update successfully")
      End With
    Catch ex As Exception
      Call transaction.Rollback()
      Call MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
    Finally
      Call .Close()
    End Try
  End With
  RefreshData()

  Call txtID.Clear()
  Call txtName.Clear()
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your connectionString? 
Are you getting any exceptions, or errors? Or is it just not updating? What sort of SQL server is it? MS SQL server?

Comment: well i'm not getting any error. the code is work. certainly i need to input manually the id, just to edit the data that display on my gridview.

Comment: Please don't post your question titles in ALL CAPS. It makes them harder to read, it's annoying, and it's considered SHOUTING (which is rude). Posting in proper case makes your question much easier to read, and will improve your chances of getting an answer. There's a reason they invented the Shift key. :-) Please use it. Thanks.

Comment: Does your connection string use attachDbFileName and user instance=true? If so you are updating one copy of e database and checking a different copy. This feature has been deprecated; please stop using it.

Comment: no i am not using that

Comment: actually the code is working. but, my problem is. every time i want to edit data. i need to manually input the id of a certain data. for ex. [ID:001 Name:test] to edit this data, i need to input this on my textbox [ID:001 Name:testing] and then the data is updated.

Comment: i want to create sub. where when i need to edit data in may DGV, it will automatically fetch the data on the textbox.

Comment: Then you should reload again your data,
By "Select * From table1".. Some thing like this

Answer (score 0):

On the ExecuteNonQuery line, capture the number of affected rows.

```
Dim rc As Integer = .ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If rc comes back as zero we can tell the query ran and found nothing to update.